# Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the source of my connect_database.php file.

```
<?php 
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/material_wallpaper/includes/variables.php'); 
$connect->set_charset('utf8');  
?>
```

and here is the error that comes.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object in /home/yukioo/public_html/wallo/includes/connect_database.php on line 3

Comment: you need to post your full code, including your db connection and query. This isn't a PHP issue, it's a database issue.

Comment: you edited your question from utf7 to utf8 without marking it as an edit.

Comment: there isn't enough code to support the question/error to reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B.:** OP edited the question from utf7 `$connect->set_charset('utf7');` to utf8 without marking it as an edit.

Querying a MySQL database does not use utf7, it uses utf8. (see my edit below)

> mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

> mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

PDO

> $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8", 'my_user', 'my_pass');

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

UTF-7 related link:

> $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-7", "EUC-JP");

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

---

**Edit:**

`$connect` and the error you received suggests the querying of a database and isn't a PHP issue as you tagged your question with.

The error may be related to your connection and/or a non-object in your query that you did not post.

If you're mixing MySQL APIs such as PDO to connect with and `mysqli_` or `mysql_` to query with, **those do not intermix.**

- **You need to use the same API from connection to query.**

In order for me to help any further, you will need to post your full code, including the connection method and its related query.

Comment: whoever thinks MySQL uses utf-7, comment and show me a link

Comment: The issue is that `$connect` isn't an object; the character set isn't an issue.

Comment: @EdCottrell I had that feeling also. I will make another edit

Comment: I first created a database using mySQL database wizard of Godaddy. Then i went to file manager uploaded my files and when i opened it. It gave me this error. Please can we contact over something like teamviewr so that you can help me fix the problem otherwise tell me what else you need to know ?

Comment: @OsamaBaloch I don't have/use teamviewr. why can't you post more relevant code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok Here is the other code.
Close_Database.php`<?php
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/material_wallpaper/includes/variables.php');
 $connect->close();
?>`

and here is the Variables.php 
`<?php
 //database configuration
 $host ="localhost";
 $user ="walloadmin";
 $pass ="a7099424";
 $database = "Wallo";
 $connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass,$database) or die("Error : ".mysql_error());
?>`

Comment: @OsamaBaloch you need to post that in your question and edit it http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32833059/edit rather than putting code in comments. including for `variables.php` if relevant.

Comment: @OsamaBaloch and this `mysql_error()` that needs to be `mysqli_error($connect)` you cannot mix `mysqli_` with `mysql_`. Keep it all the same being `mysqli_`. Those do not intermix together. Not to mention the query itself if you are querying the database.

Comment: @OsamaBaloch by the way, in your pasted code above, there are two unicode characters following `variables.php')` <= being `&#8204;&#8203;` and right before the `;` semi-colon, if that is part of your real code and that will break your code. copy/paste this exactly from here `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/material_wallpaper/includes/variables.php'); $connect->close(); ?>` and add error reporting ot your code and to display them. visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Seems like someone crapped in someone's corn flakes this morning. I hope it was me. Thanks for the drive-by downvote, and have a very beautiful day.